# How to play 2 videos in react native and that can play/pause by one button?? I am using react-native-video

Tags: react-native, video, react-hooks, react-native-video

I want to play 2 videos with play pause by one button. both Video will pause on same time and will play on same time when we clicked on button.

I am using react-native-video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give ref to both videos, video1Ref and video2Ref, and on button press just start videos on both refs.

Answer (score 0):

Both Video having different different ref and add these properties.

```
 ref={playerRef1}
    disableFocus={true}
    useTextureView={false}
    playInBackground={true}
```